# How to display a quarter circle in c++ at very beginner level?

Tags: c++, math, geometry

sorry in advance if this is messy, i'm kinda new at this.
Long story short, I just started programming for school, and one of the first questions I was asked was (translated as best as I could) as follow:

> The algorithm must display a quarter circle for a given radius (inputted by the user), using the character "*" (assuming these characters have the same horizontal and vertical alignment) Here is an example for a radius of 8:

[image: img]

So I'm sorry if this is frustrating, but we are doing pretty much only basics right now, so that means that I have very strict limitations:

- The only input I'm allowed to take is the said radius,
- Notions like float numbers were not even mentioned yet in the theoretical course, so I can't use them,
- My only mathematical operators are +,-,*,/, and modulo,
- And most importantly (and frustrating), the only loops I can use are the while and if, else loops.

So after a bit of reflection, I figured I'd go like this:
As this is the bottom right quadrant we are drawing, we can do as follow:

With the radius, we can check for each line displayed, we can do the following:

Verify that the current position on the line is inside the circle, meaning that we can use the relation x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>, where x and y become (no matter which is which exactly) our line and position in that line.

As I'm writing this, it turned out a lot more abstract and confused as I'd like, so I'm just going to link my c++ translation:

```
int main()
{
    int r, i, j;
    cout << "Rayon ?\n";
    cin >> r;
    i = 0;
    while (i < r) {
        j = 0;
        while (i*i + j*j < r*r) {
            cout << "*";
            j = j + 1;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        i = i+1;
    }
}
```

So this code is good, but it has flaws. While I'm able to replicate example results:

[image: img ok]

but when I input something like 2:

[image: img ob]

it goes bananas.

So the actual question is: I thought about this and I can't seem to be able to completely make the problem go away, while being able to reproduce the example's results. I was wondering if, with the limitations I have, there is a better solution to this, whether it involves a completely different mathematical approach, or just simple code correction I might have overlooked.

Sorry for the long read and I'm very sorry if this is not the place for something like this. All feedback is appreciated !

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger. Using this tool you can run your program one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables, on each step. You can easily inspect your program's logical decisions as it runs, and quickly figure out why its actual behavior differs from your expectations. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Invest a little bit of time to learn how to use a debugger, and you will never need to ask for help on stackoverflow.com (and stackoverflow.com isn't really a debugging service anyway).

Comment: Interesting variation of the print a triangle problem, but the basics are the same. If you look at your diagram, the only thing that changes per-line is the number of asterisks and spaces. The `while` loop is just a capable as any other type loop, so you have a good selection of tools to work with. Given the radius, you know the limit of the `x, y` region you are working within, the only thing you need to work out is how the lines *"shorten"* as you go from full length on the x-axis to the minimum length as your last line. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: In this case, as part of (or in lieu of) using your debugger, counting asterisks works as well. For the case of `2`, you would have the first line with 2-asterisks and the next and final line would have 1-asterisks. Look at your loop and increment and ask "Why doesn't my code do that?" and then take it like by line for the case when your variable is 2 and then 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make this problem easier for yourself is to step back a bit from the idea of printing a circle, and start with something a bit easier:  printing a rectangular grid.

For example, say you wanted to write a program that printed out a 80x40 solid grid of asterisks.  I imagine you could write that program easily enough (or if not, here's a hint:  nest a while-loop that iterates over the 80 columns inside a while-loop that iterates over the 40 rows).

Once you have that working and are seeing a nice solid 80x40 (or MxN) rectangle full of asterisks printed out, the only task remaining is to modify your grid-printer-program so that some of those grid-positions are printed as spaces rather than asterisks.  i.e. instead of

```
 cout << "*";
```

inside your innermost loop, you'd have:

```
 if (IsThisPositionSupposedToContainAnAsterisk(rowIdx, colIdx))
 {
    cout << "*";
 }
 else
 {
    cout << " ";
 }
```

... and then all that remains is to come up with the function itself:

```
 bool IsThisPositionSupposedToContainAnAsterisk(int rowIdx, int colIdx)
 {
    // [code to return true if the character-position
    //  at (rowIdx,colIdx) is part of the 
    //  quarter-circle-area or false if it is not]
 }
```

Comment: It's the 21st century, text characters are too cheap to meter :)

Comment: May I suggest `is_inside()`?

Comment: I know this is off-topic but I think that's overdoing it a little wtih the name. The fact that we can't use spaces  makes this a little hard to read and the filler words don't help. I think something like `positionContainsAsterisk` basically has the same information but much easier to digest. But I would say that the fact that there's asterisks is not important to the function, so something like @Bob__ suggested is even more descriptive than the long name.

Comment: Bikeshedding about the name isn’t useful.  Obviously the questioner can rename the function to whatever he prefers.